# Integrate Box IOS sdk in my ios project

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I'm trying to integrate BOX V2 IOS SDk on my ios project , the integration is fine, but when I try to login , and after I enter my username and password and granted the access , I get a white screen , and the boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed method is not called , her is my code 
**the connexion Method :**

```
-(void) connectToBox {
  [BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientID = @"my-client-id";
  [BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientSecret = @"my-client-secret";

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed:)
                                               name:BoxOAuth2SessionDidBecomeAuthenticatedNotification
                                             object:[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(boxAPIAuthenticationDidFail:)
                                             name:BoxOAuth2SessionDidReceiveAuthenticationErrorNotification
                                           object:[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session];


self.LoginCotroller = [[BoxAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithAuthorizationURL:authorizationURL redirectURI:redirectURI];

[self presentViewController:self.LoginCotroller animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

and I implement the two methods :

```
- (void)boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed:(NSNotification *)notification;
- (void)boxAPIAuthenticationDidFail:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

and the notifications methods :

```
#pragma mark - Handle OAuth2 session notifications
- (void)boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 BoxOAuth2Session *session = (BoxOAuth2Session *) notification.object;
 NSLog(@"Received OAuth2 successfully authenticated notification");
 NSLog(@"Access token  (%@) expires at %@", session.accessToken,  session.accessTokenExpiration);
  NSLog(@"Refresh token (%@)", session.refreshToken);

  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.LoginCotroller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
}

- (void)boxAPIAuthenticationDidFail:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSLog(@"Received OAuth2 failed authenticated notification");
   NSString *oauth2Error = [[notification userInfo]     valueForKey:BoxOAuth2AuthenticationErrorKey];
   NSLog(@"Authentication error  (%@)", oauth2Error);

   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   });
}
```

I dont know what wrong with my code.So if any one can help.Thanks

Comment: once you enter your credentials it will show a screen where you will have 2 options 1. grant 2.decline are you able to see this screen. If yes, so once you click on grant button it will call web service and get access token in POST method (this will take @30-50 seconds)

Comment: i i see that and i accept that the app access and edit my files. and nothing happened even after 2 min

Comment: delete app and run again same thing happened to me today now its working

Comment: yes i did it too but still the same problem , can you show me your code ? so i can see what wrong with my code ?

Comment: this got nothing to do from our side.. it is inside the SDK only. give me ur email id i'll send the box code mine charangiri.p@gmail.com

Comment: ok I just sent you email , thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50127/discussion-between-hatim-haffane-and-charan-giri)

Comment: @CharanGiri you have box code send it to me my mail id: aruna.tumma06@gmail.com me also facing same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest adding your controller as an observer for BoxOAuth2SessionDidRefreshTokensNotification as well to call boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed: method. BoxOAuth2SessionDidRefreshTokensNotification is posted when a new access-token is created/refresed.